# Do the "do my homework for me" questions deserve a canned close reason?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I just ran into a question asking to place a couple dozen notes described in scientific pitch notation onto a scale. That's obviously someone trying to get the community to do his homework for him, and obviously off topic. Are those common enough to deserve their own close reason, or uncommon enough to just be dropped into the "other" category?

Comment: What is the harm in just leaving it open?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So far we haven't had many of them, so I reckon just using free form text to say why you are voting to close will be fine. If we get a lot of them we can look at adding a custom close reason.

Comment: We should also note that we are currently maxed out on our close reasons. We _could_ petition the SE devs for another slot, but we need a really good reason to.

Comment: Sometimes it's really satisfying to type your own close reason into the 'other' box, when one really deserves it ;)